# Understanding ACK numbers

Tags: linux, tcp, wireshark, ack

I try to understand the reason of unordered ACK numbers. I have the following logs in wireshark:

```
34936 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3595656117 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2   0.003662105 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 66  80 → 34936 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=32
    3   0.003691751 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34936 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0
    4   0.003803721 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 HTTP    767 POST /jrd/webapi?api=GetSystemStatus HTTP/1.1* (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
    5   0.024447941 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 54  80 → 34936 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=714 Win=32128 Len=0
    6   0.052296708 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 70  80 → 34936 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=714 Win=32128 Len=16 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    7   0.052296845 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 HTTP/JSON   528 HTTP/1.1 200 OK , JavaScript Object Notation (application/json)
    8   0.052364039 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34936 → 80 [ACK] Seq=714 Ack=17 Win=64256 Len=0
    9   0.052930703 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34936 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=714 Ack=492 Win=64128 Len=0
    10  0.061251843 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 74  34938 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3595656179 TSecr=0 WS=128
    11  0.064187519 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 54  80 → 34936 [ACK] Seq=492 Ack=715 Win=32128 Len=0
    12  0.064187779 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 66  80 → 34938 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=32
    13  0.064330872 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34938 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0
    14  0.065632767 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 HTTP    772 POST /jrd/webapi?api=GetSMSStorageState HTTP/1.1* (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
    15  0.066381036 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 74  34940 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3595656184 TSecr=0 WS=128
    16  0.074954073 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 66  80 → 34940 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=32
    17  0.075028197 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34940 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0
    18  0.075349695 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 HTTP    772 POST /jrd/webapi?api=GetConnectionState HTTP/1.1* (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
    19  0.080664337 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 70  80 → 34938 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=719 Win=32128 Len=16 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    20  0.080664489 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 HTTP/JSON   304 HTTP/1.1 200 OK , JavaScript Object Notation (application/json)
    21  0.080744236 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34938 → 80 [ACK] Seq=719 Ack=17 Win=64256 Len=0
    22  0.081363475 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  34938 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=719 Ack=268 Win=64128 Len=0
    23  0.084534363 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 54  80 → 34938 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=719 Win=32128 Len=0
    24  0.084606985 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1 TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 22#1] 34938 → 80 [ACK] Seq=720 Ack=268 Win=64128 Len=0
    25  0.084649572 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 54  80 → 34940 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=719 Win=32128 Len=0
    26  0.084649729 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 54  80 → 34938 [ACK] Seq=268 Ack=720 Win=321
    27  0.086781498 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 TCP 70  80 → 34940 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=719 Win=32128 Len=16 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
```

1. In string number 8 Seq=714 Ack=17. But in string number 9 Seq=714 Ack=492. I thought that Ack here 714+17=731. How Ack is calculate here and why it is 492? The same question about calculation Ack number in string 22 where Ack=268, not 736 as i expected.
2. In string number 9 there is FIN ASK flag following by SYN flag. But in string number 13 i see ASK flag following by SYN flag. I don't see FIN flag.

Thank you a lot for any answers. I need to understand low-lewel TCP basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add `Seq` anc `Ack` in the same direction. Sequence number refers to your outgoing data, Acknowledgement indicates how much incoming data you've received.

So packet 8 says "I'm sending the data starting at sequence 714, and I've received everything up to (but not including) 17". Packet 9 says "I'm sending data starting at sequence 714, and I've received everything up to (but not including) 492". In between those packets it processed packet 7 from the server, which contains 492-17=475 bytes of TCP payload (the frame size is 528, but that includes headers, which aren't counted in TCP sequence numbers).

Comment: Barmar, thank you very much! I have read lots of article about tcp flow. But only from your detailed answer I understood Seq ACK counting.